# Logic for Binary numeric promotion

Tags: java, logic

Please explain me the logic for binary numeric promotion on the below code.

```
boolean flag = 'A' < 'a';
System.out.println(flag);// prints true.
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a promotion? I think two arguments are char and has a well defined order.

Comment: I read it in a book for java. writer name Khalid a. Mughal.

Comment: hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576302/what-is-numeric-promotion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the `char` primitive data type was defined as a 16-bit Unicode character, with values in the hexadecimal range from `0x0000` to `0xFFFF`. When you compare two `char` values, it's that 16-bit hex value that's used.

In your specific case, `A` is represented by `0x0041` and `a` by `0x0061`, so `'A' < 'a'` will evaluate to `true`.

For reference: [Unicode (The Java Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html)

Comment: But where does the binary numeric promotion fit in this?

Comment: @AJ- It doesn't really in this example. This is just a case of `char` being represented by numeric data behind the scenes. There's no promotion needed. Promotion would take place if you were comparing an `int` to a `long` value, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's called promotion when you are comparing two different types (usually numbers) and one of them will be converted to the other so they can be compared. like:

```
int x = 5;
double y = 6;
if (x < y)
    ...
```

In Java `int` and `double` can be compared. In that case, `int` will be converted to `double` implicitly.

In your case there is no promotion. A character stored in memory as a number (in Java it's based UTF-16 standard and stored as exactly 2 bytes like a `short`) and in `'A' < 'a'` integer numbers are compared.