# How HeapByteBuffer converts byte array to short

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bytebuffer

I have a java program, where I m trying to convert a byte array to short.

```
byte arr[] = {-1,-1};
int value = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getShort();
```

the value I get from above is `-1`. But its actual value should be `65535`.

I decided to take a look how the library converts the byte array value to actual short. On getting deep inside the functions, I think I saw the function inside this class `java.nio.Bits` which is doing the actual work of converting byte array to short, its implementation is like this

```
private static short makeShort(byte var0, byte var1) {
        return (short)(var0 << 8 | var1 & 255);
}
```

The function is taking care of the negative value of 2nd byte but not for the 1st byte.

I m not sure but shouldnt the return statement of the above function should be like this

```
private static short makeShort(byte var0, byte var1) {
        return (short)((var0 & 0xFF) << 8 | var1 & 255);
}
```

java version : 8

Thank You.

Comment: `short` is signed. Its maximum is 32767.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, this program in java prints the value `65535`.
```
byte arr[] = {-1,-1};
System.out.println((short)(arr[0] & 0xff)<<8 | (arr[1] & 0xff));
```

Comment: `(short)(arr[0] & 0xff)<<8 | (arr[1] & 0xff)` is no longer a `short`. `|` operator promotes it to `int`.

Comment: oh, I see. But what about the implementation of the above ByteBuffer function is that correct? shouldnt there be `var0 | 0xff` to convert negative value to positive?

Comment: By the way, `char` is unsigned. So if you want to read the value as an unsigned two byte quantity, you can use `int value = ByteBuffer.wrap(arr).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN) .getChar();` Be careful to always promote the result to `int` to avoid confusing output when printing…

Comment: You can use `var0` instead of  `var0 & 0xFF` in `return (short)((var0 & 0xFF) << 8 | var1 & 255);` because the upper bits are ignored anyway when casting to `short`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`short` is signed. Its maximum value is 32767, and minimum is -32768.

`ByteBuffer.getShort` cannot return a `short` value of 65535, no matter how you change its implementation, because 65535 is not a valid value for `short`.

The implementation of `getShort` is correct. The bits of the two bytes are both `1111 1111` (= -1), and the resulting `short` is `1111 1111 1111 1111` (also = -1).

But you *do* assign what `getShort` returns, to an `int` variable `value`, so `value` can store 65535. However, the implicit conversion from `short` to `int` *sign-extends*, instead of *zero-extends*, the bits, so you still get a value of -1.

You can use `Short.toUnsignedInt` to treat the signed `short` as unsigned, and get an `int`.

```
int value = Short.toUnsignedInt(byteBuffer.getShort());
// value is 65535
```

And the implementation of `toUnsignedInt` is probably what you have expected:

```
public static int toUnsignedInt(short x) {
    return ((int) x) & 0xffff;
}
```

---

Side note: the implementation of `makeShort` does `var1 & 255`, because `|` causes [numeric promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576302/5133585). `var0 << 8 | var1` would convert `var1` to an `int` by sign-extending it. This might add some extra 1s that shouldn't be there. Consider `var1 = 0` and `var2 = -1`. The bit patterns look like this when both sides are converted to `int`.

```
var0 << 8: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 (originally 0000 0000)
var1     : 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 originally 1111 1111)
```

ORing them and cutting off the most significant 16 bits would give 16 '1's, instead of the expected `0000 0000 1111 1111`.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation, I think I get most of it. I have one question though why does the function is trying to convert the second byte to positive value, shouldnt that also needs to be left as it is?

Comment: Not exactly what I expected, as the type cast is entirely obsolete.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh it’s not converting the second byte “to positive value”, the `var1 & 255` *eliminates the upper bits*. Think about how *binary or* works and you should understand why this is necessary.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh The `|` operator causes numeric promotion, so it would have converted (sign-extended) `var1` to `int` otherwise, when we only want the least significant 8 bits.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh Consider the case of `makeShort((byte)1, (byte)-1)`. The bit patterns are `0000 0001` and `1111 1111`. The latter would get sign-extended to 32 '1's. When you OR that with `0000 0001`, every bit becomes 1, and the result is 16 '1's after cutting off 16 bits from the `int`, when it should have been `0000 0001 1111 1111`.

Comment: yeah I got it, this apart from your's and @Holger explanation, this answer also helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380062/what-does-value-0xff-do-in-java. Thanks again Hogler and Sweeper for the explanation.